# Why is the output of these 2 programs not same

Tags: c

I am trying to find the numbers that are not divisible by 3,5,7 and counting them
And printing the ones that are divisible

The two approaches are

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int count=0;
   
   for(int i = 1; i<=500;i++)
   {
       if(i%3==0 && i%5==0 && i%7==0) {
            printf("%d \n", i);
       }
       else {
           count++;
       }
   }
    printf(" the count is : %d \n", count);
}
```

```
/*
WAP to count the numbers from (1-500) which are not divisible by 3, 4 and  
*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int count=0;
    
    for(int i = 1; i<=500;i++)
    {
        if(i%3!=0 && i%5!=0 && i%7!=0) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d \n", i);
        }
    }
     printf(" the count is %d \n", count);
}
```

The problem is that the output should be same but it is not

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Change `&&` to `||` in the second one. `a AND b` == `(!a) OR (!b)`

Comment: Have you heard about the principle of inclusion-exclusion? Regardless, the 2nd if statement is not the negation of the 1st.

Comment: Recall [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  The inverse of `(i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0) && (i % 7 == 0)` is `(i % 3 != 0) || (i % 5 != 0) || (i % 7 != 0)`.

Comment: When in doubt, plug in an example value (e.g. "3" for "i") and work out the expression on paper.  You'll quickly discover that "(i%3!=0 && i%5!=0 && i%7!=0)" is *NOT* the negation of "(i%3==0 && i%5==0 && i%7==0)"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because these two if statements are not opposite from each other. The negation from

```
if(i%3==0 && i%5==0 && i%7==0)
```

would be

```
 if(!(i%3==0 && i%5==0 && i%7==0))
```

which changes equals to not equals, but also changes ANDs to ORs. So the second code should have something like this

```
if(i%3!=0 || i%5!=0 || i%7!=0)
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out that `if (i % 3 != 0 || i % 5 != 0 || i % 7 != 0)` is a hell of a lot easier to read -- especially for eyes over 50.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Or even `if( i % 3 || i % 5 || i % 7 )`... none of us is getting younger `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Amen to that `:)`